# filename is is changed when copied from one path to another unicode encoding gets changed

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, filesystems, nfs

**mypath** directory containsfiles globbed from FastCopy directory, I copied file to **mypathd**
directory and performed following and observed that the filename are different

**listing specific files from mypath**

```
>>> l = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if f.startswith('02748571-00000003-00004861')]
>>> l
['02748571-00000003-00004861-n@#SEDARDoNotDelete#2018#FDP#renewal#final#consentementRCGT-fran\xe7ais-PDF.pdf', '02748571-00000003-00004861-n@#SEDARDoNotDelete#2018#FDP#renewal#final#consentementRCGT-fran\xe7ais-PDF-SCRIBE.txt.bad']
```

**listing specific file from mypathd**

```
>>> l = [f for f in listdir(mypathd) if f.startswith('02748571-00000003-00004861')]
>>> l
['02748571-00000003-00004861-n@#SEDARDoNotDelete#2018#FDP#renewal#final#consentementRCGT-fran\xe6\xa0\xa9s-PDF.pdf', '02748571-00000003-00004861-n@#SEDARDoNotDelete#2018#FDP#renewal#final#consentementRCGT-fran\xe6\xa0\xa9s-PDF-SCRIBE.txt.bad']
>>>
```

**I feel that globbed filenames are local latin encoded and when copied to another location unicode encoded but what makes it happen. Destail info would be highly appriciated**

```
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'ANSI_X3.4-1968'

 echo $LANG -> no output
```

used perl module to glob file from fastcopy directory
I am using linux distro. working in redhat boxes

**It happens to be that the filename is latin encoded only in home/docs/xyz folder  which is a network file system**

```
mount | grep docs
/docs/xyz on /home/docs/xyz type nfs (rw,proto=tcp,sloppy,addr=xxx.xxx.xx.xx)
```

So how can I possibly find out the locale of the nfs how can I proceed with the problem??

Comment: It is not a simple Latin1 utf-8 conversion because 2 characters after the original `ç` have been changed. You should say what if your OS, Python version, and how you used FastCopy. Additionaly Python declares that your file system encoding is plain ASCII while the original file name contains a `'ç'`. You really should add more details...

Comment: you do no write which operating system, and which filesystem. In any case, filename of such length are beyond safety. (You can use them, but you must know well about support on all your chain [do not forget backups!])

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I am working with linux servers NFS mount.